# Can not get correct value of indexPath.row in prepareForSegue when UILabel or UIImageView in a cell is tapped,

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, segue

I am developing iOS App with UITableView.

When UILabel or UIImageView in a cell is tapped, segue is called and move to another screen.

I am writing down the following code, however I can not get correct value of indexPath.row in prepareForSegue.The value is always 0.

```
- (void)goToDetail: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
    NSLog(@"aaa");
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.article = _article[indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"bbb%d",indexPath.row);
    }
}
```

NSLog says following.

```
2014-08-08 17:50:23.267 eleventhtest[27374:60b] bbb0
2014-08-08 17:50:23.269 eleventhtest[27374:60b] aaa
```

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As just one of the possible options, you can set tag for label/imageView and gesture recognizer when you are creating cells. The tag would be the same as the indexPath.row.
In goToDetail method you can assign this tag to some internal property, and then use it in prepareForSegue.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can solve the problem with your advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling `goToDetail` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method AND have a segue wired from the prototype row to your detailViewController, then the segue fires BEFORE the goToDetail method.

Solution: segue directly from your view controller to your detailViewController and call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Also you can create a NSIndexPath property and set the value in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, the segue would then use that property instead of trying to access the [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].